# What is the best way to store information that can be accessed from within the code readily?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, distributedcache

I have been developing SharePoint solutions for quite a while I came across this situation where I have to implement customized revisions for the users because of the complex revision process.

The issue I am facing is for the concurrency, the requirement is that if there are two users trying to make a revision (revision is a new item in the document library with a few attributes same as the actual item) for an item only one of them should be given access and the other one should not see the custom form.

I somehow have to store a hashtable or if there's any other better suggestion to keep track of the current revisions being made, in memory, accessible to the farm and available on all app servers in the farm. I know about the distributed cache but using it is not recommended by Microsoft. Please suggest how do I implement this lock system on top of SharePoint.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use check-out/check-in? When a document is checked out nobody else can make edits until it is checked back in. There is an option that says "Require Check Out" in library settings under "Versioning Settings" that will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I can't use check-in check out because I don't have the item created until and unless I fill the form and submit it. On submission it will create a new revision which is a copy of the original item + the attributes filled on the form.

Comment: I am looking for a mechanism where I can control that no two users are shown the revision form for one particular item

Comment: Could you use the impersonating step in a workflow to modify the permissions of the item so that only the creator and some admin group can see it?